# Select Two different values from the same column in MySQL and show results

Tags: mysql

I have the following data:

```
id  pointValue  datetime
620 0           1-2-15 13:33
621 1           2-2-15 13:33
622 2           3-2-15 13:33
623 3           4-2-15 13:33
```

I need to create a SQL query when id=620 and id=623 and get the following:

```
id1 pointValue1 datetime1       id2 pointValue2 datetime2
620 0           1-2-15 13:33    623 3           4-2-15 13:33
```

What I really want to do is to combine both result set in a simple row. I have tried with

> SELECT MPV.id, MPV.pointValue
>   FROM pointvalues AS MPV WHERE MPV.id = "620"
>   UNION
>   SELECT MPV.id, MPV.pointValue 
>   FROM pointvalues AS MPV WHERE MPV.id = "629"'

but this gives me different rows and I need just one.

Thanks in advanced,
Izaskun

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT MPV.id, MPV.pointValue, MPV1.id, MPV1.pointValue
FROM pointvalues AS MPV
LEFT OUTER JOIN pointvalues AS MPV1
ON MPV1.id = "629"
WHERE  MPV.id = "620"
ORDER BY MPV.id;
```

Comment: Your research found you an answer, well done.  Remember that asking questions, even easy ones is actually pretty hard.